# Including a Concatenated Field in a SQL WHERE...IN Clause

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a SQL statement that creates a concatenated field.  How do I then use that concatenated field as Part of a WHERE...IN clause?  See code below that is currently not working.  The SQL works when I remove everything from the second "and" down.

```
SELECT *, a.LastName + a.FirstName as LastFirst
FROM MST_MEMBER_DEMOGRAPHICS as a
WHERE a.GroupID = 'abcCompany'
And 
a.PersonType = 'D'
and 
LastFirst in
('LastName1FirstName1','LastName2FirstName2','LastName3FirstName3',.....etc)
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating data in the first place? That's the concern of the view-level (not SQL `VIEW`, but the "view layer" in your application).

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the expression, use a subquery, or CTE:

```
SELECT md.*, (md.LastName + md.FirstName) as LastFirst
FROM MST_MEMBER_DEMOGRAPHICS md
WHERE md.GroupID = 'abcCompany' AND
      md.PersonType = 'D' AND
      (md.LastName + md.FirstName) IN ('LastName1FirstName1', 'LastName2FirstName2', 'LastName3FirstName3', .....etc)
```

But my preferred method is a lateral join:

```
SELECT md.*, v.LastFirst
FROM MST_MEMBER_DEMOGRAPHICS md CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES (md.LastName + md.FirstName)) v(LastFirst)
WHERE md.GroupID = 'abcCompany' AND
      md.PersonType = 'D' AND
     v.LastFirrst IN ('LastName1FirstName1', 'LastName2FirstName2', 'LastName3FirstName3',.....etc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use your concatenated text `LastFirst` value in the `WHERE` because the "logical" evaluation order of a SQL `SELECT` query is actually `FROM > WHERE > GROUP BY > HAVING > SELECT > ORDER BY`, so expressions made in the `SELECT` part aren't usable anywhere except the `ORDER BY` part (though some RDBMS like MySQL do allow the use of expression aliases, conceptually it's the same as using an outer query).

I recommend against using `WHERE x IN ( a, b, c, ... )` in your example because it isn't "correct" (see my notes below regarding false positives) - but mainly because it's an alternative representation of the `OR` operator when you really want `OR ( x AND y )`.

I note that `WHERE IN` generally don't work with parameters anyway (as each `IN` element member has to be its own parameter) you'll have to use (SQL-injection-prone) dynamic SQL, in which case you should use `( x = a1 AND y = b1 ) OR ( x = a2 AND y = b2 ) OR ...` expressions as these are [SARGable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean) and will run a *LOT* faster.

(I note that in MS SQL Server, the execution plan for `x IN ( a, b, c )` is identical to `( x = a OR x = b OR x = c )`).

Another reason to not perform string concatenation like this is because of the risk of false-positives: (Warning: contrived example) Suppose you have two people: `John Smith` and `Johns Mith` - using your approach would mean both people would match a query for either name.

So I would do it like so:

```
SELECT
    *,
FROM
    MST_MEMBER_DEMOGRAPHICS AS a
WHERE
    a.GroupID = 'abcCompany'
    AND
    a.PersonType = 'D'
    AND
    (
        ( a.LastName = 'LastName1' AND a.FirstName = 'FirstName1' )
        OR
        ( a.LastName = 'LastName2' AND a.FirstName = 'FirstName2' )
        OR
        ( a.LastName = 'LastName3' AND a.FirstName = 'FirstName3' )
    )
```